# Register global module -cannot find module

Tags: angular

I purchased a Fuse template and it contains custom components located in `@fuse` directory.

I copied over this directory to my new project.
However, I get a red squiggly line (error) and says

> Cannot find module '@fuse/fuse.module'.ts(2307)

How do I register this?

```
import { FuseModule } from '@fuse/fuse.module';
import { FuseSharedModule } from '@fuse/shared.module';
import { FuseProgressBarModule, FuseSidebarModule, FuseThemeOptionsModule } from '@fuse/components';
```

Comment: Did you add at `app.module.ts`? Also if you're lazy loading I think you still have to add it on the modules you need it as well.

Comment: Yes, I added this to app.module.ts

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have installed a package called '@fuse', If you use @fuse for your import it won't work, because the app cannot find such a module.

Since you have copied the directory over to your application, you'll have to give the path to the folder:

```
import { FuseModule } from '../../@fuse/fuse.module';
```

or simple add path alias in your `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
 "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@fuse/*": ["src/app/@fuse/*"],
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things

1. If this module is only exposing components(which i think is the case):

   - add the module to imports section (inside `NgModule` decorator) of each module where 
     your are using this module.
   - I suggest having a shared module where you do the above and import this shared module into all other modules
2. If this module is only exposing services:

   - add this module **ONLY** in app module.
3. For cases where a module exposes both(bit difficult):

   - check out using for root in angular docs